# Span style float:left is breaking div block

Tags: html, css

I'm working on maintaining a bit of code that's out of whack at the moment. Basically, we have a `<div>` tag with it's own style settings, and we have multiple logic tags that will display different `<span>` tags, which will hold different bits of data.

What I'm seeing is that when I'm using a `<span>` tag with a style setting `float: left;`  this is causing the `<div>` tag's color box to not wrap around the `<span>`.

Here's a sample of the code:

```html
<div id="testData" style="padding:4px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #999; background: #d1d1d1; text-align:right;">
    <span style="padding: 3px 1 1 1; float:left;">
         TestData: Float Left
    </span>    
</div>
```

I need this span tag to go left, due to requirements. Was wondering what my options are for this to work?

[Original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLfw5wc7/)

Comment: For starters, I would strongly advise against using inline styles. Keeping your styles in one place (stylesheets) is the easier route to go in most cases (as far as maintaining code is concerned).

Comment: Actually, the styles that are shown in the div and span tags in the section above are pulled from the CSS. However, even there I'm seeing the same result (the shaded box does not wrap around the text that is in the span tag)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gLfw5wc7/3/

```
#testData {
    padding:4px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #d1d1d1;
    text-align:right;
}
#testData:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
#testData > span {
    padding: 3px 1px 1px;
    float:left;
}
```

This is known as a [*clearfix*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best). When floating an element, it gets out "the flow" of the document. This also means that its width and height aren't taken into account by the parent. That's why `#testData` seems to collapse: it thinks it doesn't have content. To fix this there are some options. The easiest is to use `overflow`, however, that's bad practice imo. In this particular case it works, but in some other cases you won't be able to use it because content that overflows the parent will either be hidden (`overflow: hidden`) or a scrollbar will appear (`overflow: auto`).

The most common and proper solution is to use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to fix this. `:after` is such a pseudo element (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181729/should-i-use-single-or-double-colon-notation-for-pseudo-elements) for `:after` vs `::after`). Basically, a pseudo element can create an element in CSS that is not visible in HTML.

Every time you use `float`, you'll be needing a clearfix. Therefore it's useful to create a `.clear` class which you can apply to every element that needs to clear floats. It would look like this.

HTML

```
<div id="testData" class="clear">
    <span>
         TestData: Float Left
    </span> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clear:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Now you can add `class="clear"` to every element that needs to be cleared. If you are into SASS, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711317/1150683) helpful but considering you are new to HTML, I'd suggest sticking to HTML and CSS first.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to the parent div:

```
#testData {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gLfw5wc7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to make use of `clear: both`

```
#testData:after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLfw5wc7/2/)

Other solutions:

Using `overflow: hidden`

```
#testData {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or making a dummy element `<div class="clearBoth"></div>`

**HTML**

```
<div id="testData" style="padding:4px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #999; background: #d1d1d1; text-align:right;">
    <span style="padding: 3px 1 1 1; float:left;">
         TestData: Float Left
    </span>    
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearBoth {
  clear: both;
}
```